# How to adjust Highslide JS to new responsive design

Tags: responsive-design, highslide

I used Highslide JS about 5 years ago on this site: http://wela.ctc.edu/academy12-13.aspx (example page).  Now I'm redesigning the site use Twitter.Bootstrap and am trying to figure out how I can tweak the Highslide popups to work in a small device width.  Is this possible or should I use find another solution to implement? I've played around with the setting parameters in my highslide-with-html.js file, but the results have been unsatisfactory.  If it is possible to use Highslide in a responsive design, would be grateful for any URLs to look at.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Highslide adapts very well to small devices if you're opening images. The expander is purpose-built to do just that - display the image as large as it can without exceeding the boundaries of the viewport.

But when opening anything else - an expander with HTML content, an iframe, etc. - the expander must initially be a fixed size. You can put a resize handle on it, but that's not really good enough for handling everything from a smartphone to a large monitor.

Without rewriting Highslide JS, overcoming this limitation would require that your page do its own detection of the viewport size, then either modify the call to htmlExpand() on the fly, probably with some jQuery manipulation, or change the .highslide-html CSS class width. The latter approach (targeting the CSS) seems like it would be easier.